# library projects cant be found and R.java wont be built.

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a couple of libraries which are not being detected in my eclipse project.

[image]

The problem is its showing up with a cross in properties -> Android

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: import these libraries in your workspace.. not in your libs folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first delete google play services from eclipse and clean project

For google play services first install Google play Services

SDK Manager -> Extras -> Google play Services

after installing go to

File->import->your SDK folder path ->extras->extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

Answer (score 0):

**Do not copy-paste** these libraries inside your 'libs' folder. Instead, **import** those to your workspace(not from libs folder) and refer them from there.

Answer (score 0):

RightClick On Project->property->Android->Add->select google play services lib ->Apply->ok

Comment: Copy the C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib library project into the source tree where you maintain your Android app projects.

    If you are using Eclipse, import the library project into your workspace. Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse to the copy of the library project to import it.

Comment: For google play services first install Google play Services

SDK Manager -> Extras -> Google play Services

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Library project in your application, all library project should be imported first in your working **Workspace**

```
How to add Library projects
```

**RightClick on Your Project> Go to Properties >Android>Click on Add**

[image]

**Then add all the required library project**

[image]

**Then click Apply then Ok**

Hope this will help you..